# swifty and assign array

Tags: swift, swifty-json

Using swift and swifty i'm trying to do the following:

```
var jsonArray: [JSON] = []

for entryMap in userDistrictEntryMaps
{
    var map: UserDistrictEntryMap = entryMap

    let entry = JSON(
        [
            "itemID": String(map.entryID),
            "data": map.entryData
        ]
    )

    jsonArray.append(entry)

}

let parameters =  JSON(
    [
        "token"      : sessionMap.token,
        "districtID"  : String(sessionMap.defaultDistrictID)
    ]
)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add "entrys" to parameters and assign it jsonArray data

I tried the following and it gives an error.

```
    parameters["entrys"] = JSON(jsonArray).arrayValue
```

Any idea on what i'm doing wrong?

**Update 1**

Ok the problem is parameters is set as let.  I changed it to var and
changed assign to:

```
 parameters["entrys"] = JSON(jsonArray).rawString()
```

But using rawString() is propbably invalid cause if i print the raw data it has to many back slashes:

[\n  {\n    \\"data\\" : \\"QXJyZXN0cyA4OjUyIFBN\\",\n         \\"passdownItemID\\" : \\"17\\"\n  }...

**Update 2**

I modified my code and this works:

```
var entrys: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

for entryMap in userDistrictEntryMaps
{
    var map: UserDistrictEntryMap = entryMap

    let entry =
    [
        "itemID": String(map.itemID),
        "data":  map.entryData
    ]


    entrys.append(entry)

}


var parameters1 =
    [
        "token"      : sessionMap.token,
        "districtID"  : String(sessionMap.defaultDistrictID),
        "entrys"       : []
    ]

parameters["entrys"] = entrys
```

Comment: The compile error is:

Cannot assign a value of type '[JSON]' to a value of type 'JSON'

Comment: The error is saying you're trying to assign an array of JSON to an object of type JSON, that's not an array

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using and posted the answer in my question.

```
var entrys: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

for entryMap in userDistrictEntryMaps
{
    var map: UserDistrictEntryMap = entryMap

    let entry =
    [
        "itemID": String(map.itemID),
        "data":  map.entryData
    ]


    entrys.append(entry)

}


var parameters1 =
    [
        "token"      : sessionMap.token,
        "districtID"  : String(sessionMap.defaultDistrictID),
        "entrys"       : []
    ]

parameters["entrys"] = entrys
```